# Does this break the statelessness of a RESTful API?

Tags: rest, restful-architecture

Take this design of an API:

- `/articles/{id}` - Returns an article. Client provides a token in the header to identify them.
- `/updated-articles` - Returns collection of articles that have been updated since the client's last call to this endpoint, and only includes articles that this client previously requested. Client provides a token in the header to identify them.

The second enpoint doesn't fit very well with me. The design motivation of that second enpoint is that the **client does not need to track the time of their last requests**. Is this breaking the "statelessness" constraint of RESTful APIs? An alternative approach would be `/updated-articles?since=YYYY-MM-DD` but this would require clients to remember

Comment: Why not `/articles?updated_since=YYY-MM-DD` instead?

Comment: As a struture, that does look well. The reason for "why not" is that the client would need to track their value for `YYYY-MM-DD` which goes against the requirements.

Comment: Your client doesn't have to be stateless. Only your server app.

Comment: Understood. Yet the business requirements I received in effect didn't allow me to design an API according to RESTful principles. I was asked to keep state on the server. I guess that's just a hard mis-match.

Comment: Honestly whoever is handing you this requirement is just making things harder than they have to be. Did you ask why?

Comment: The "why" is to make the implementation easier for the 3rd part client. I think it's a process of education of the benefits of a RESTful architecture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your "token" is basically a client id, and the fact of remembering the date of their last access is keeping a client-state on the server.

Think about it : If you had to scale up your service, could you simply plug-in a new server, copy your service's files, and redirect via a round-robin algorithm on one or another of the two server (without having them sharing informations) ? Clearly no, because you would need your table `tokens<->date of last consultation` shared between the two servers. So no it's definitely not stateless.

Plus, I don't understand your point :

> An alternative approach would be /updated-articles?since=YYYY-MM-DD
>   but this would require clients to remember

Wouldn't a token require a client to remember ? On the contrary, this way would be RESTful, since the client-state (the date of last consultation) would be kept on the client side.

Comment: While I agree on most part of you comment, I want to cite [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) on the topic of statelessnes: `... The session state can be transferred by the server to another service such as a database to maintain a persistent state for a period and allow authentication.` Database connections are often shared between multiple servers and thus enables the server to shift the current state to the DB-Layer so a further server processing a follow-up request should be able to access the state.

Comment: "Wouldn't a token require a client to remember ? ". I'm not sure I follow. The token has a static value over time, it's an access token. The client would need to remember the value for `YYYY-MM-DD`. The business requirements handed down to me were "the client should not need to keep track of their last call date".

Answer (score 0):

**Basically, no, I don't think your second resource would break statelessness.**

I think it's okay to have your client's keep track of their own 'updated at' time stamp. Your api should be stateless. The client doesn't have to be stateless.

If anything the client should retain a lot of state. The client will be a device central to one user and their specific needs. It's responsible for keeping track of the user's needs and current state. In this situation someone will have to store that time stamp. I think it should be your clients, not your server.

This is just my opinion though.

I did find a write up over the true meaning of statelessness that I think could benefit you as well [here](http://soundadvice.id.au/blog/2009/06/).

Answer (score 0):

We should avoid creating endpoints with no related entity. So instead of `/updated-articles?since=<timestamp>` a better approach should be:

- `/articles?updated=true&since-last-request=true` or
- `/articles?updated-since-last-request=true`

If the intended result should affect all clients. Meaning every request time stamp must be kept on the server. Or

- `/articles?updated-since=<timestamp>`

If the intended result depends on each client behavior. That seems to be your case.

The choice between the former or the latter (or both) depends on the use case. But the main point is to **avoid** creating endpoints with no related entity and having special cases being defined by parameters.

As a guideline:

> > Endpoints are *substantives*, *adjectives* are parameters and *verbs* are the HTTP request methods

This also means a simple 'GET /articles' means returning **ALL** articles. To avoid abuse you may issue proper 4xx codes depending on the case.

Comment: I see that what you're saying seems to make sense, but could you please explain further how `/updated-articles` have "no related entity"?

Comment: @edev what I meant is that *articles* are entities but *updated articles* are not, they are just a sub-set of the former. On my designs I avoid creating such sub-sets as endpoints (entities) and prefer to define them using parameters.